# Ruby on Rails - destroy_all on 70k+ records with 450k associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

From my understanding, `destroy_all` destroy all records, their associations, and does callbacks. However, it instantiates all of the records, which in my case is taking hours. It's going through about 70k records in one table, along with about 450k associated records in another table. It also just chews up through all the 16GB of memory trying to do this as well.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle this so that it's scalable across large number of rows.

The downfall that I see of `delete_all` is that it doesn't go through `dependent: :destroy` and destroy dependent associations. In this case, would it be best for me to just simply hard code the dependent deletes? So if `Book` `has_many` `:pages, dependent: :destroy`, would it be better for me to go through `Pages.where(book_id: xyz).delete_all` and then call `Book.delete`, or is there another best way for me to use `delete_all` to also catch its associated records?

Comment: How deep is the relational chain? I guess either way it seems like a bulk operation like this would be best fully thought out, wrapped in a transaction and executed directly against each table separately (`delete_all`) rather than using the dependent destroy chain

Comment: Agreed. Right now the main association that has 70k records just has 2 more associations. Its second associated table has about 450k records and the third one has about 100k. I agree. I think doing a recursive `delete_all` seems best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alter the database and set [`on delete cascade`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/) on the relevant foreign keys. Then when a record is deleted, all its associations will also be deleted. Then you can use the much more efficient `SomeClass.delete_all`.

Rails doesn't let you alter an existing foreign key. You need to remove it and add it back. For example, let's say you have...

```
class Building
  has_many :rooms, dependent: :destroy
end

class Room
  belongs_to :building
end
```

Then you'd write a migration like...

```
change_table :rooms do |t|
  t.remove_foreign_key :buildings
  t.foreign_key :buildings, on_delete: :cascade
end
```

This doesn't drop the column, it just drops and re-adds the foreign key constraint.

Then you can `Building.where(...).delete_all`. This will issue a single `delete from buildings where ...` statement. The database will efficiently delete all associated `rooms` as well.

Comment: This is very interesting!! So would this be two options that I could go with -- creating a migration that would allow me to efficiently run `delete_all` on new tables, whereas the other one would be another option to implement it from the database side?

Comment: @LewlSauce No, they're both the same option. Set up `on delete cascade`, use `Books.where(...).delete_all`, and let the database handle deleting the associations. Note this will not run callbacks. `on delete cascade` is the normal SQL way of handling this situation. Rails callbacks make it complicated.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Schwern "rails callbacks make it complicated" isn't exactly fair because they definitely serve a purpose e.g soft deletes, audit trails, permission checks etc. Obviously these could be db triggers but business logic in the db is certainly not my preferred method however in this instance it would make sense.